# Python Dictionary Comprehension Not Outputting As Expected

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I am playing around with dictionaries, and thought how would I create a dictionary using comprehensions. I thought

```
{k:v for k in [0,1,2] for v in [5,8,7]}
```

would print as

```
{0:5, 1:8, 2:7}
```

But instead it prints as

```
{0: 7, 1: 7, 2: 7}
```

Why is this happening and what modifications would I need to make to get the first output?

Comment: The keys 0, 1 & 2 will all be set to 5 on the first iteration, then 8 then 7

Comment: @BrutusForcus Ah I see, so would it better to do this using the zip() function?

Comment: you could try zipping like: {k: v for k, v in zip([0, 1, 2], [5, 8, 7])}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list comprehension is equivalent to nested loops:

```
result = {}
for v in [5, 8, 7]:
    for k in [0, 1, 2]:
        result[k] = v
```

So each iteration of the outer loop sets all the keys to that value, and at the end you have the last value in all of them.

Use `zip()` to iterate over two lists in parallel.

```
{k: v for k, v in zip([0, 1, 2], [5, 8, 7])}
```

You can also just use the `dict()` constructor:

```
dict(zip([0, 1, 2], [5, 8, 7]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have trouble with a comprehension, unroll it into the equivalent loops. Which in this case goes:

```
mydict = {}
for v in [5,8,7]:
    for k in [0,1,2]:
        mydict[k] = v
```

Each successive assignment to `mydict[k]` overwrites the previous one.